# Issues deploying to Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my web app to Firebase, and I have gotten through the deploy script successfully, but when I go to the url I get the Open Hosting Documentation page instead of my app.

This is my firebase.json file:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "/",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And this is my project directory view:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the above is all correct, it just took a while to populate in firebase I guess.